# где взять zImage в установленной системе

Tags: debian

Нужно запустить **qemu-system-arm**.

Для запуска он очень хочет **zImage**. Я пока не очень понял, что это такое. И не понял, где взять в уже готовой и развернутой через **debootstrap** системе.

Если что - моделируется процессор Allwinner A20 (sunxi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно установить пакет linux-image, дебутстрап его не ставит по умолчанию. Если система без initramfs (генерируется с дровами под конкретное ядро), то можешь просто распаковать пакет с ядром нужной архитектуры и достать оттуда ядро.